# Pointer to member: works in GCC but not in VS2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14

I'm trying to implement a "property" system to convert C++ instances into JSON and vice versa. I took a part of the code from Guillaume Racicot's answer in this question ([C++ JSON Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549906/c-json-serialization#34165367)) and simplified it.

Here is how I proceed. I have a `Property` class:

```
template <typename Class, typename T>
struct Property {
    constexpr Property(T Class::* member, const char* name) : m_member(member), m_name(name) {}

    T Class::* m_member;
    const char* m_name;
};
```

m_member points to a specific member of `Class`

Let's say I want to define properties for a `User` class, I would like to be able to proceed like this, to be able to assign members a property name:

```
class User
{
public:
    int age;

    constexpr static auto properties = std::make_tuple(
        Property<User, int>(&User::age, "age")
    );
}
```

This code compiles and works correctly in GCC(http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/276ac099068579fd) but not in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. I get those errors:

```
main.cpp(19) : error C2327 : 'User::age' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
main.cpp(19) : error C2065 : 'age' : undeclared identifier
main.cpp(20) : error C2672 : 'std::make_tuple' : no matching overloaded function found
main.cpp(20) : error C2119 : 'properties' : the type for 'auto' cannot be deduced from an empty initializer
```

Would there be a workaround to make it work in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3?

Comment: Does the `Property` constructor take one argument or two?

Comment: @aschepler I think he made a mistake in typing, because in the [shared-code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/276ac099068579fd) the constructor has two arguments.

Comment: @aschepler Two arguments, corrected

Comment: Please post a full but short `main.cpp` file: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @pts Yes, I put the code here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/276ac099068579fd

Comment: The exact same code does not compile in VS2015(update 3)

Comment: I don't think MSVC can see inside a class before it's fully defined (`User::age` is not known until `};` is parsed).

Comment: @RustyX And it seems that "properties" absolutely needs to be defined inside the User class :(

Comment: Yep. Very curious if anyone can preserve its `constexpr`ness in MSVC.

Comment: @Michael Why do you think it absolutely needs to be defined inside the User class?  It just needs be accessible from the User class name.

Comment: As to whether MSVC or GCC is correct, read the 2 answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564009/error-c2327-not-a-type-name-static-or-enumerator)

Comment: This is not an answer so I'm not posting it as one, but there are much easier ways to do what you are trying to do. The member to function pointer does not actually buy you anything. You can do all of this with simple pointers, and substantially simplify your syntax without losing a single thing. The basic building block of reflection is just a function that given an instance of a class, returns a tuple of pairs of typed pointers and string literal names. That's all. Pointer to member just adds lots of needless syntactic complexity.

Comment: @NirFriedman True in this case, but if you want to do anything more complicated than JSON serialization, then having a _constexpr_ tuple of members can buy you simplicity and performance.

Comment: @Oktalist You can write a constexpr function that returns the tuple I described as well. Of course, it will take an instance of the object implicitly or explicitly, and so to use it in a constexpr context you need a constexpr instance of the object. But you cannot use the current properties for anything useful without a copy of the object either. I'm open to examples to the contrary, but I think this is just an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @NirFriedman Suppose reflection is used for several different operations, e.g. JSON, protobufs, lexicographical comparison, hashing. Suppose that certain members are to be excluded from certain operations. You can mark these members by putting flags in the tuple. In the operation's implementation you can skip the flagged members with `if constexpr`. You could do it with metaprogramming too, and as you're already using metaprogramming to unpack the tuple, the only thing you would lose is the separation of concerns, coupling together skipping with unpacking. So it depends.

Comment: With C++17 constexpr lambdas `&User::age` could be replaced with `[](auto&& x)->decltype(auto) { return x.age; }`.

Comment: @Michael I reported the bug here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3106015/unable-to-form-a-pointer-to-member-in-some-constant-expressions

Comment: In the meantime, @Oktalist solution will work just fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My preferred workaround is just to replace the `properties` member data with a `properties` member function:

```
class User
{
public:
    int age;

    constexpr static auto properties() { return std::make_tuple(
        Property<User, int>(&User::age, "age")
    ); }
};
```

This works because in the definition of a member function, the class is considered to be completely defined. It also has the desirable attribute that `properties` doesn't need to be separately defined if odr-used.

Answer (score 3):

MSVC doesn't know enough about `User` when it wants to calculate the type of `properties` to know it has a member `age`.

We can work around the problem.

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{constexpr tag_t(){};};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};

template<class T>
using properties = decltype( get_properties( tag<T> ) );

class User
{
public:
  int age;

};
constexpr auto get_properties(tag_t<User>) {
  return std::make_tuple(
    Property<User, int>(&User::age, "age")
  );
}
```

In the JSON reflection code, simply replace `std::decay_t<T>::properties` with `get_properties( tag<std::decay_t<T>> )`.

This has a few advantages.  First you can retrofit some classes you do not own or wish to modify with properties seamlessly.  With careful namespace use and ADL enabling the point of call, you can even do so for (some) types within `std` (with oublic members only; pair at the least).

Second it avoids possible ODR-use requirements on properties.  Properties is now a `constexpr` return value not some global data that may require storage.

Third it permits properties to be written out-of-line with the class definition like above, or inline as a `friend` within the class, for maximium flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

If it is absolutely needed to properties be defined in User class maybe you  could make use of helper templated constexpr function like:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename Class, typename T>
struct Property {
    constexpr Property(T Class::* const member) : m_member{ member } {}

    T Class::* const m_member;
};

template <class T, class V>
constexpr Property<T, V> get_age_property() {
    return  Property<T, V>(&T::age);
}

class User
{
public:
    int age;

    constexpr static std::tuple<Property<User, int>> properties = std::make_tuple(
         get_age_property<User, int>()
    );

};

int main()
{
}
```

It seems to compile in [webcompiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) i.e. VC++ 19.00.23720.0